# Can I jump back to the beginning of a method using 'redo' in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, redo

In the [Poignant Guide](http://poignantguide.net/ruby/chapter-5.html#section5) this example of the `redo` keyword is given:

```
class LotteryTicket
  def self.new_random
    new(rand(25) + 1, rand(25) + 1, rand(25) + 1)
  rescue ArgumentError
    redo
  end
end
```

It's supposed to keep calling `new` until all three random numbers are unique. But after I typed this code in and ran it a few times, I got this error: `LocalJumpError: unexpected redo`. I looked up the `redo` keyword elsewhere and it looks like it is only supposed to work for loops and iterators. So why did why try to use it like this in his example? How should this method be rewritten to work correctly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

He must have meant to [use `retry`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_loops.htm), not `redo`.

Answer (score 3):

`redo` restarts a block:

```
l = lambda {puts "hi"; redo}
l.call
```